# new user is getting created

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

this is my models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
idno=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
email=models.CharField(max_length=40)
choices = (
    ('C', 'C'),
    ('C++', 'C++'),
    ('Java', 'Java'),
    ('Python', 'Python'),
)
intrest = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=choices)
marks=models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

this is my views where i am asking the user to choose their intrest

```
def timeline(request):
intrest=Profile.objects.all()[0].intrest
if intrest =='':
    if request.method=="POST":
        choice=request.POST['choice']
        print(choice)
        profile=Profile(intrest=choice)
        profile.save()
```

this code is creating a new profile with blank name and email how can i save this current information to the same user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a separate model for interest and marks and use a foreign key.

Answer (score -1):

Get those pieces of information from POST and save them as well:

```
choice = request.POST['choice']
name = request.POST['name']
email = request.POST['email']
profile=Profile(intrest=choice, name=name, email=email)
profile.save()
```

As long as you are sending them through the POST request of course.

Comment: i am saving name and email in different function. i just want to update my profile with new intrest